# Settings from the .editorconfig are not respected in Omnisharp / VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp, editorconfig

I'm trying to set up my Visual Stuido Code so that Omnisharp uses settings supplied in an `.editorconfig`, as described in https://www.strathweb.com/2019/07/editorconfig-support-in-omnisharp-and-c-extension-vs-code/. I set up a new .net-core 3.1 console project using `dotnet new console` and added a `.editorconfig` file to the root of the project. Then I filled in the exact values from the blog post (see below) and enabled editorconfig and roslyn analyzers for OmniSharp. I even tried both methods for enabling the features: In `settings.json` and in `omnisharp.json`. But when I used the refactoring capabilities of OmniSharp to create a field from a constructor parameter the generated name was equal to the parameter name instead of being prefixed with `_`. Restarting the OmniSharp server multiple times didn't help as well.

**.editorconfig**

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false
dotnet_naming_style.instance_field_style.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.instance_field_style.required_prefix = _
```

**Sample class with auto-generated field**

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string a;  // This should have been named _a

    public MyClass(string a)
    {
        this.a = a;  // Should be without the this.-prefix
    }
}
```

What I am using:

- VS Code version 1.42.1
- C# extension for VS Code version 1.21.12
- Omnisharp server (part of the extension) version 1.34.13

I would appreciate it alot if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

I've also had trouble with formatting lately.

I think I finally have a stable working solution.

- I disabled all other code formatting extensions that I had previously installed and tried.  This included commenting out all settings related to those extensions in `settings.json`
- I removed the `.editorconfig` file that had been at my project root.
- I added the following to `settings.json`

```
"[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
 },
"omnisharp.enableMsBuildLoadProjectsOnDemand": true,
"omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": true,
"omnisharp.enableRoslynAnalyzers": true,
```

- I added the following to the top of my `omnisharp.json` file.

```
{
  "RoslynExtensionsOptions": {
    "enableAnalyzersSupport": true,
  },
  "FormattingOptions": {
    "enableEditorConfigSupport": true,
```

- Recreate `.editorconfig` at the project root [using the example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/roslyn/master/.editorconfig) linked in the post you mentioned above.  *This was important for me because the `.editorconfig` I had previously used was not working even after all the other changes.*
- Restart VS Code
- Reload your project

I didn't see the option for creating `readonly string _name` until after restarting everything.

[Edit]
The following answer [from @Stephen may also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071289/70870) for you.

```
#IDE1006
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private.symbols  = private_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private.style = camel_case
```